# Is spotify play button mandatory for iOS App?

Tags: ios, spotify, autoplay

I am planning to build an iOS App wherein my App would auto-play all songs from my defined playlist (one after the other). So as soon as my App ia launched, the first song in my playlist would auto-play, then, as soon as this song ends, the second song in the playlist should auto-play. Also I do not want user to access Play and Pause buttons while the song is playing.

Please suggest if this is possible. Would Spotify reject my App if Play and Pause button are not shown to users?

Comment: Maybe it's just my ignorance but how on earth could spotify reject your iOS (App Store) app?

Answer (score 1):

If it's  to meet requirements of [Human Interface Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/AppDesign/AppDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH19-SW1)
that they wouldn't reject you. How I know, your app is meeting requirements. (but I didn't read all HIG documentation)